# Heat Map with DataFrame

Tags: pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I have a pandas data frame of the form

```
    State   RF      LOG     KNN     MLP     DT      LDA     AB
0   AR      0.95    0.87    0.81    0.89    0.81    0.84    0.87
1   FL      0.83    0.86    0.85    0.86    0.89    0.82    0.85
2   NJ      0.89    0.81    0.88    0.83    0.89    0.84    0.83
3   NV      0.77    0.72    0.89    0.79    0.79    0.73    0.70
4   TX      0.71    0.70    0.71    0.77    0.70    0.70    0.92
5   CA      0.69    0.81    0.81    0.88    0.88    0.60    0.89
```

How could I make a heat map, for example, on Seaborn, that in the X-axis has the names of the columns: [RF, LOG, KNN, MLP, DT, LDA, AB], in the Y-axis the names of the column State [AR, FL, NJ, NV, TX, CA], and the corresponding values, displayed in the squares, are the "heat" indicators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you index the columns of the states, you can draw a heat map directly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme()

data = '''
    State   RF      LOG     KNN     MLP     DT      LDA     AB
0   AR      0.95    0.87    0.81    0.89    0.81    0.84    0.87
1   FL      0.83    0.86    0.85    0.86    0.89    0.82    0.85
2   NJ      0.89    0.81    0.88    0.83    0.89    0.84    0.83
3   NV      0.77    0.72    0.89    0.79    0.79    0.73    0.70
4   TX      0.71    0.70    0.71    0.77    0.70    0.70    0.92
5   CA      0.69    0.81    0.81    0.88    0.88    0.60    0.89
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df.set_index('State', inplace=True)
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `seaborn` at all, you can use the built-in functionality of `pd.DataFrame.style`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io


data = '''
    State   RF      LOG     KNN     MLP     DT      LDA     AB
0   AR      0.95    0.87    0.81    0.89    0.81    0.84    0.87
1   FL      0.83    0.86    0.85    0.86    0.89    0.82    0.85
2   NJ      0.89    0.81    0.88    0.83    0.89    0.84    0.83
3   NV      0.77    0.72    0.89    0.79    0.79    0.73    0.70
4   TX      0.71    0.70    0.71    0.77    0.70    0.70    0.92
5   CA      0.69    0.81    0.81    0.88    0.88    0.60    0.89
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df.set_index('State', inplace=True)
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='Reds')
```

[image]