# How to only show months for bar chart xticklabels rather than showing dates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I am having a data frame containing dates, stations id and rain fall mm/day. i am trying to generate a bar plot. I am using matplotlib subplot to generate the bar graph. Once i run the below code it generates a bar chart(shown below) with messy dates in x axis. i am analyzing the data from 2017-04-16 to 2017-08-16. I want to show months like april 2017, may 2017 and so on. Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi= 136, figsize=(16,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
df1[216].plot(ax = ax1, kind='bar', stacked=True)
df1[2947].plot(ax = ax2, kind='bar')
df1[5468].plot(ax = ax3, kind='bar')
df1[1300].plot(ax = ax4, kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Here is the output i am getting

[image: output]

This is the dataframe i am having

[image: df1]

Comment: To increase the chances of getting a good answer, I suggest you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can easily be copy-pasted and run. You could share enough of your dataset to reproduce the problem, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66161425/14148248), or you could create a sample dataframe like in the examples shown in [the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot).

Answer (score 0):

Bar plots in pandas are designed to compare categories rather than to display time-series or other types of continuous variables, as stated in the [docstring](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

> A bar plot shows comparisons among discrete categories. One axis of
> the plot shows the specific categories being compared, and the other
> axis represents a measured value.

This is why the scale of the x-axis of pandas bar plots is made of integers starting from zero and each bar has a tick and a tick label by default, regardless of the data type of the x variable.

You have two options: either plot the data with `plt.bar` and use the date tick locators and formatters from the [matplotlib.dates module](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) or stick to pandas and apply custom ticks and tick labels based on the datetime index and formatted using appropriate [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) like in this example:

```py
import numpy as np               # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd              # v 1.2.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.4

# Create sample dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1234)
date = pd.date_range('2017-04-16', '2017-06-16', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.exponential(scale=7, size=(date.size, 4)), index=date,
                  columns=['216','2947','5468','1300'])

# Generate plots
axs = df.plot.bar(subplots=True, layout=(2,2), figsize=(10,7),
                  sharex=False, legend=False, color='tab:blue')

# Create lists of ticks and tick labels
ticks = [idx for idx, timestamp in enumerate(df.index)
         if (timestamp.month != df.index[idx-1].month) | (idx == 0)]
labels = [tick.strftime('%d-%b\n%Y') if (df.index[ticks[idx]].year
          != df.index[ticks[idx-1]].year) | (idx == 0) else tick.strftime('%d-%b')
          for idx, tick in enumerate(df.index[ticks])]

# Set ticks and tick labels for each plot, edit titles
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set_title('Station '+ax.get_title())
    ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=0, ha='center')

ax.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
plt.show()
```

[image: labels_months]