# Adjusting tick frequency of embedded Matplotlib graph in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, xticks

I am creating a currency converter application in Python that shows the conversion between two currencies selected and maps their ratio onto a graph displayed on the side.

The graph displays the pattern of that ratio for the last 30 days of the current day.

The data going in the graph is well, but the main problem is that the labels at the x-axis are a mess.

The highlighted bit is the code that creates the graph.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

If my method doesn't suit well, please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14148248), only the output/graph should be shared as an image. To increase the chances of getting a good answer, I suggest you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be copy-pasted. It should include some sample data that reproduces the problem you are facing. You could paste it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66161425/14148248) or generate it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14148248).